# Xamarin.Forms: Hide ListView on Map click?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.forms.listview

My app is really simple: it displays a `Xamarin.Forms.Map` in the top half and a `ListView` on the bottom half.

This is my `xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200"
            x:Name="MyMap"
            IsShowingUser="true"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is app in the emulator:

[image]

I would like to hide the `ListView` when I *click* on the map, and at the bottom something that says "Show List". More or less something like this:

[image]

I added an event handler like so in class `MainPage` (similar to [trouble in Hide/show of listview on a click in xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185256/trouble-in-hide-show-of-listview-on-a-click-in-xamarin-android)), but it doesn't build:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    /* Fills ListView and plots points in map */
    ListView_Pets.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<StackLayout>` I would propose to use `<Grid>` to achieve this kind of Layout:

**Xaml Code:**

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
        <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200" 
                  x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Text="Show List" TextColor="LightGray">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listSection" IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="200">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private bool isListVisible;
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    isListVisible = !isListVisible;
    listSection.IsVisible = !isListVisible;
 }
```

You can update the show hide logic using binding, if you are using MVVM Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps as follows:

- Add Button or Label for display "Show List" inside stacklayout in **Views**.
- Now create Command and Property for map, listview and button and
  handle from **ViewModel** by Binding.
- When press on map,invoke custom command in **ViewModel** and write
  logic for hiding list visibility, adjusting size for height
  and showing button visibility.
- When press on button,invoke click custom command in
  **ViewModel** and write logic for showing list visibility,
  adjusting size for height and hiding button visibility.